# insert into table not working

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm trying to insert data into two tables in the database, one of the two queries work even though they are the same, only the column names and database name are changed.

Here's the code for insert,...

```
$requesttitle = $_POST["requesttitle"];
                $requesturl = $_POST["requesturl"];
                $requestcap = $_POST["requestcap"];
                $requestdestype = $_POST["requestdestype"];
                $requestdbtype = $_POST['requestdbtype'];
                $accountid=$_SESSION['username'];
                $deptname = $_POST['deptname'];
                $contactname = $_POST['contactname'];
                $contactnum = $_POST['contactnum'];
                $contactemail = $_POST['contactemail'];
                $startdate = $_POST['startdate'];
                $enddate = $_POST['enddate'];

                if(trim($requesttitle)=="") return "<p>Error in submitting request. Request Title is empty!</p>";
                if(trim($requesturl)=="") return "<p>Error in submitting request. Request URL is empty!</p>";
                if(trim($requestcap)=="") return "<p>Error in submitting request. Storage Capacity is empty!</p>";
                if(trim($requestdestype)=="") return "<p>Error in submitting request. Design Type is empty!</p>";
                if(trim($requestdbtype)=="") return "<p>Error in submitting request. Database Type is empty!</p>";
                if(trim($deptname)=="") return "<p>Error in submitting request. Requesting Department is empty!</p>";
                if(trim($contactname)=="") return "<p>Error in submitting request. Contact Person is empty!</p>";
                if(trim($contactnum)=="") return "<p>Error in submitting request. Contact Number is empty!</p>";
                if(trim($contactemail)=="") return "<p>Error in submitting request. Contact E-mail is empty!</p>";
                if(trim($startdate)=="") return "<p>Error in submitting request. Contact E-mail is empty!</p>";
                if(trim($enddate)=="") return "<p>Error in submitting request. Contact E-mail is empty!</p>";

                //$sql = "insert into webhostrequest (requesttitle, requesturl, requestcap, requestdestype, requestdbtype, accountid, deptname, contactname, contactnum, contactemail, startdate, enddate, recentact) values ('$requesttitle', '$requesturl', '$requestcap', '$requestdestype', '$requestdbtype', '$accountid', '$deptname', '$contactname', '$contactnum', '$contactemail', '$startdate', '$enddate', now())";
                //$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error in submitting request. $sql".mysql_error());

                $sql2 = "insert into req_servicerequest (title, url, memory, design, database, accountid, deptname, contactname, contactnum, contactemail, startdate, enddate, recentact) values ('$requesttitle', '$requesturl', '$requestcap', '$requestdestype', '$requestdbtype', '$accountid', '$deptname', '$contactname', '$contactnum', '$contactemail', '$startdate', '$enddate', now())";
                $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ("Error in submitting request. $sql2".mysql_error());
```

And here's the error,...

> Error in submitting request. insert into req_servicerequest (title,
>   url, memory, design, database, accountid, deptname, contactname,
>   contactnum, contactemail, startdate, enddate, recentact) values ('A',
>   'http://www.kimbra.org/', '500', 'HTML/XHML/XML', 'DB2', 'test', 'UST
>   - Steps', 'james', '09151273507', 'test@reply.mail', '2012-04-10', '2012-05-24', 'now()')You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'database, accountid, deptname, contactname,
>   contactnum, contactemail, startdate,' at line 1

Comment: database is a reserved word. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: That code needs some optimization and sql injection sanitizing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

database is a keyword in MySQL.  Escape it like this: `database`, or better, rename your column.